# While loop with if statements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm solving some coderbyte.com challenges and I run into some problems. This is the task:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function `ArithGeo(arr)` take the array of numbers stored in `arr` and return the string "Arithmetic" if the sequence follows an arithmetic pattern or return "Geometric" if it follows a geometric pattern. If the sequence doesn't follow either pattern return -1.
>
> An arithmetic sequence is one where the difference between each of the numbers is consistent, where as in a geometric sequence, each term after the first is multiplied by some constant or common ratio. Arithmetic example: [2, 4, 6, 8] and Geometric example: [2, 6, 18, 54].
>
> Negative numbers may be entered as parameters, 0 will not be entered, and no array will contain all the same elements.

```
function ArithGeo(arr) { 
      var x = 0;
      var s = 0;
      var allObjects = [];
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        while(x<arr.length-1) {
          var diff = arr[x+1]-arr[x];
          allObjects.push(diff);
          x++;
        }
        
       while(s<allObjects.length) {
          console.log(allObjects.length);
         
          if(allObjects[s]===allObjects[s+1]) {
            console.log('entered if');
            return "Arithmetic";
            s++;
            
          }
          else if(allObjects[s+1]%allObjects[s]===0) {
            return "Geometric";
            s++;
          }
          else {
            return "-1";
            s++;
          }
         }
        
        
       
      }
             
    }
       
    // keep this function call here 
    // to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
    ArithGeo([1,2,3,100]);
```

It enters into first if statement only once, and it should enter 3 times, for every element in `allObjects` array. Can you tell me why this is?

Comment: why are you incrementing `s++` in condition

Comment: Since you `return` in every condition clause it will only check one object and then return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `return` breaks function execution, and nothing else is executed afterwards.

```
var f = function () {
    these();
    things = will + be * 3;
    executed();
    return 4;
    while(anything) {
        after++;
        a = "return statement";
        won = 't';
    }
};
f();
```

Wild guess: maybe [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) will help you out (jumps to the next iteration)

Comment: Thanks. Is there some way to combine'continue' and return statement?

Comment: @boofighter You are anyways returning a String, so store the return value in some `var` and return the var at end of the function.

Comment: I created a function with return statement, which I call inside if statement.  That way it works! Thanks.